# How to use multiparameter String functions in Rust?

Tags: function, oop, rust, parameter-passing, variadic-functions

I want to make a `to_string()` fn in Rust with `&self` as parameter, and calling the references of the elements of `&self` inside the function:

```
//! # Messages
//!
//! Module that builds and returns messages with user and time stamps.

use time::{Tm};

/// Represents a simple text message.
pub struct SimpleMessage<'a, 'b> {
    pub moment: Tm,
    pub content: &'b str,
}

impl<'a, 'b> SimpleMessage<'a, 'b> {

    /// Gets the elements of a Message and transforms them into a String.
    pub fn to_str(&self) -> String {
        let mut message_string =
            String::from("{}/{}/{}-{}:{} => {}",
                         &self.moment.tm_mday,
                         &self.moment.tm_mon,
                         &self.moment.tm_year,
                         &self.moment.tm_min,
                         &self.moment.tm_hour,
                         &self.content);
        return message_string;
    }
}
```

But `$ cargo run` returns:

```
    error[E0061]: this function takes 1 parameter but 8 parameters were supplied
      --> src/messages.rs:70:13
       |
    70 | /             String::from("{}/{}/{}-{}:{}, {}: {}",
    71 | |                          s.moment.tm_mday,
    72 | |                          s.moment.tm_mon,
    73 | |                          s.moment.tm_year,
    ...  |
    76 | |                          s.user.get_nick(),
    77 | |                          s.content);
       | |___________________________________^ expected 1 parameter
```

I really don't understand the problem of this syntax, what am I missing?

Comment: In rust, there are no variadic functions, so that what you are doing is not working. You can only use macros for an unspecific amount of parameters, like `format!`, `println!`, `write!` (which will all fall back to `format!`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably meant to use the `format!` macro:

```
impl<'b> SimpleMessage<'b> {
    /// Gets the elements of a Message and transforms them into a String.
    pub fn to_str(&self) -> String {
        let message_string =
            format!("{}/{}/{}-{}:{} => {}",
                         &self.moment.tm_mday,
                         &self.moment.tm_mon,
                         &self.moment.tm_year,
                         &self.moment.tm_min,
                         &self.moment.tm_hour,
                         &self.content);
        return message_string;
    }
}
```

`String::from` comes from the [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html) trait, which defines a `from` method that takes a single parameter (hence "this function takes 1 parameter" in the error message).

`format!` already produces a `String`, so no conversion is necessary.